# Automatically add to list

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a small issue manipulating data.

I have a few check-boxes to select various items on the screen, which in turn inputs relevant data such as item name, price, etc. The issue is that these names have to go onto a invoice, and I cannot get the names to transfer onto the invoice nicely.

The invoice has to record the items, but it needs to check to see if a item has been already applied to the invoice and this is what I'm having problems with.

How can I get items to collectively display on a sheet without any additional interactions (I just click the relevant checkbox instead of manually typing it in), and display them nicely.

The items 'Underlay and Extended Warranty' need to be displayed one after another, and not 2-3 boxes away.

Example:

`Underlay Extended Warranty`

I don't want this:

`Underlay`

`Extended Warranty`

Is there a solution to this?

*Update:*

This happens if I do it the way I know:

[image: Invoicing Screen]

[image: Actual Invoice]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by making a custom Excel VBA Macro that basically tells us the cell that is free which is closest to the top of the invoice:

```
Public Function GetApplicableCell() As String
    Range("C20").Select
    If (IsEmpty(Range("'Invoice Sheet'!C20").Value)) Then
        GetApplicableCell = "C20"
    End If
    If (IsEmpty(Range("'Invoice Sheet'!C21").Value)) Then
        GetApplicableCell = "C21"
    End If
    If (IsEmpty(Range("'Invoice Sheet'!C22").Value)) Then
        GetApplicableCell = "C22"
    End If
    If (IsEmpty(Range("'Invoice Sheet'!C23").Value)) Then
        GetApplicableCell = "C23"
    End If
    If (IsEmpty(Range("'Invoice Sheet'!C24").Value)) Then
        GetApplicableCell = "C24"
    End If
End Function
```

It can be called by a `=GetApplicableCell()` from within the worksheet, and we can work with this to produce a workable solution.